# Java- How to ask "if a JButton is disabled then ___"

Tags: java

so I'm a 6th grader who's trying to program a TicTacToe program using netbeans 8.1 and java.

This is my code so far (for the sake of simplicity i've only included the code of one button):

```
public class TicTacToe extends JFrame{
    static Random computerGenerate = new Random();
    static int rounds = 0;
    static JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    static JButton s1 = new JButton();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gui();
    }
    public static void Gui() {
        JFrame Gui = new JFrame("TicTacToe");
        Gui.setVisible(true);
        Gui.setResizable(false);
        Gui.setSize(320, 340);
        Gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        Gui.add(panel);
        s1.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);
        s1.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 50));
        s1.addActionListener(new Response());
        panel.add(s1);
    }
    private static class Response extends TicTacToe implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() == tictactoe.TicTacToe.s1) {
                s1.setText("X");
                s1.setEnabled(false);
                rounds += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    public static void Moves() {
        if (rounds == 1) {
            int computerStartPos = 1 + computerGenerate.nextInt(8);
            switch (computerStartPos) {
                case 1:
                    if (button"s1" is disabled)) {
                        computer will generate a new starting position for the AI
                    } else {
                        button s1 will be disabled and it will show a "O" to show the computer has selected the square
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The section which I have a problem with is the very last method, method Moves(). 

What I'm trying to do is, after the player has selected their starting square, the computer will generate a number, 1-9 which will determine its own starting position. 

The problem I have is if the player has already selected that button before the computer, I need the computer to re-generate a new number as its starting point.

My idea to solve this is "if s1.setEnabled() is equal to false, then the computer will re-generate a new number which corresponds to its new starting position".

Is this posible to write? This is only a small time project but I would appreciate the help.

Oh, and I have been told I'm incorrectly using static in java, however if I don't include "static" in the code netbeans gives me errors for days until all of my code is like RED ERROR!!!! If anyone knows why or can explain how to properly use it please do as well :D

 I sincerely appreciate any help I receive.

Comment: First of all, `Static methods in java belong to the class (not an instance of it). They use no instance variables and will usually take input from the parameters, perform actions on it, then return some result. ` Secondly yes you can check that. `if(! isEnabled()){ ... }`  Remember there is `!` at the start of the condition which will check for enabled or not!

Comment: How to get rid of the static error: learn about object-oriented programming concepts, and use them. There are many tutorials on the subject that are easily found. You will want to get most of your code out of the static main method and create and use objects instead.

Comment: Oh @HovercraftFullOfEels . Thanks for the warn! Shall take care next time

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yes I did recognize that but even when I try to take that out I get a face full of errors I'm trying to reread Oracle's own java guide on static to see if I can understand it better sorry man

Comment: @HovercraftFullofEels Thanks man

Answer (score 1):

There is a [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#isEnabled--) for checking whether a button is enabled or not...

```
if (button.isEnabled()) {

}else {}
```

and

> *if I don't include "static" in the code netbeans gives me errors for
>   days until all of my code is like RED ERROR!!*

you  Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field...

try dont using static things and create instances instead...

you can use as start point:

remove the static keyword from the fields, define a construtor and create an instance in the main method..

like this:

```
// YOU NEED A CONSTRUCTOR
public TicTacToe () {
computerGenerate = new Random();
panel = new JPanel();
s1 = new JButton();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
TicTacToe demoExample = new TicTacToe ();

demoExample.Gui();
}
```

Comment: Right, but this would probably create a circular dependency between th model and the view which should be avoided. The only effect of disabling a button should be, well, disabling the button.

Answer (score 0):

> Static methods in java belong to the class (not an instance of it).
>   They use no instance variables and will usually take input from the
>   parameters, perform actions on it, then return some result

Secondly yes you can check that.

```
if(! s1.isEnabled())
{ 
    ... 
}
```

Remember there is `!` at the start of the condition which will check for enabled or not!